# Adding threshold to custom black and white filter

Tags: objective-c, image, core-image

```
- (UIImage *)pureBlackAndWhiteImage:(UIImage *)image {

unsigned char *dataBitmap = [self bitmapFromImage:image];

for (int i = 0; i < image.size.width * image.size.height * 4; i += 4) {

    if ((dataBitmap[i + 1] + dataBitmap[i + 2] + dataBitmap[i + 3]) < (255 * 3 / 2)) {
        dataBitmap[i + 1] = 0;
        dataBitmap[i + 2] = 0;
        dataBitmap[i + 3] = 0;
    } else {
        dataBitmap[i + 1] = 255;
        dataBitmap[i + 2] = 255;
        dataBitmap[i + 3] = 255;
    }
}

image = [self imageWithBits:dataBitmap withSize:image.size];

return image;
```

}

I am very new using core Image. I found this code online and What it does is transform an Image to pure black and white (no grey). What I want to do is to be able to modify the threshold. Meaning I want to be able to make it whiter or blacker. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Play with the `(255 * 3 / 2)` expression, until you are happy with the result.
The higher this value is, the more black pixels you will have.

Comment: Yeah I suspected that, but what I don't understand is why he didn't just write a number if thats the threshold. What is he calculating?

Comment: 255 is the max value for a color channel. There is 3 color channels added so he multiplies by 3, but divides it by 2 to set the threshold value. It's just a way to explicitly write his thinking. You can put a whole number it will work as well ;)